# не удается преобразовать из "string" в "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>"

Tags: c#

У меня не получается при нажатии на кнопку написать одну строку в файле

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (toolStripTextBox1 != null)
            {
                ((WebBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
                string lines = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
                File.AppendAllLines (@"C:\DB\History\dbhistorybeta.txt", lines);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\DB\History\dbhistorybeta.txt", lines);
```